# Cannot Convert type SOAP after Conversion to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wsdl

I am new to Visual Studio and C#. I converted an old project to work with Visual Studio 2010.I am getting an error on the line where the code is trying to type casting a web reference object inheriting 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol' to a local object inheriting the same. I have been searching web and tried few things with no success.

Also before conversion,I had the project compiled on Visual Studio 2008 and it builds fine without any error. The line that gives error after conversion to and in Visual Studio 2010 does not throw any error on Visual Studio 2008.I cannot continue with VS 2008 because I am running with some separate issue which possibly will be another SO question if I cannot resolve this.

I appreciate all the responses and of course a possible solution.

Comment: what exactly is the error message?

Comment: Is Sytem.Web.Services already a reference in your project?

Comment: @VictorMukherjee : Cannot convert type. #Marijke: Yes it is already in my project

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).